# super().__repr__() not returning expected results

Tags: python, class, init, super, repr

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, nameInput, addressInput, dateOfBirthInput):
        self._name = nameInput
        self._address = addressInput
        self._dateOfBirth = dateOfBirthInput
    def getName(self):
        return self._name
    def getAddress(self):
        return self._address
    def getDateOfBirth(self):
        return self._dateOfBirth
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Name: %s \nAddress: %s \nDate of Birth: %s' % (self._name, self._address, self._dateOfBirth)
```

The first class will output properly if I put in something like `kat = Person('CC','9th Street','1990')`. But I can't get it to work correctly when I try to call it from within a subclass, it just leaves everything blank.

```
from Person import Person

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, nameInput, addressInput, dateOfBirthInput, employeeNumberInput, dateOfHireInput):
        super().__init__(nameInput, addressInput, dateOfBirthInput)
        self._employeeNumber = employeeNumberInput
        self._dateOfHire = dateOfHireInput
    def getEmployeeNumber(self):
        return self._employeeNumber
    def getDateOfHire(self):
        return self._dateOfHire
    def __repr__(self):
        return super().__repr__() + '\nEmployee Number: %s \nDate Of Hire: %s' % (self._employeeNumber, self._dateOfHire)
```

If I were to input something like `kat = Employee('CC','9th Street','1990','12345','2017')` into the block above I get nothing, am I missing something obvious, I've rewritten it a few different ways to match examples but neither my ways nor the examples work for me.

Comment: How are you printing it? `repr(kat)`?

Comment: print(kat) is what I'm using but I tried repr(kat) and I get the same.

Comment: Don't use `__repr__` for this anyway.  It's not supposed to be used for presenting formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

So after some fiddling it seems there isn't anything wrong at all, whether it runs or not seems to be decided by what I run it with. I wrote it in Visual Studio and it didn't work in that, but it works fine when I shove it in Idle.

Comment: It sounds as though your Visual Studio may have been configured for Python 2.

Answer (score -1):

Do this in your Employee class

```
class Employee(Person):
...:     def __init__(self, nameInput, addressInput, dateOfBirthInput, employeeNumberInput, dateOfHireInput):
...:         super(Employee, self).__init__(nameInput, addressInput, dateOfBirthInput)
...:         self._employeeNumber = employeeNumberInput
...:         self._dateOfHire = dateOfHireInput
...:     def getEmployeeNumber(self):
...:         return self._employeeNumber
...:     def getDateOfHire(self):
...:         return self._dateOfHire
...:     def __repr__(self):
...:         return super(Employee, self).__repr__() + '\nEmployee Number: %s \nDate Of Hire: %s' % (self._employeeNumber, self._dateOfHire)
```

this will work for your module

Comment: That changes nothing.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have added ```super(Employee, self) ``` and it works for me